# How can i avoid index.php from URL in codelgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using apache server,I need to remove index.php from uri

Comment: Please. Who casts upvotes on such a question? Does it show *any* research effort?

Answer (score 5):

Open config.php and replace

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php" by $config['index_page'] = ""
```

In .htaccess file add

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. To solve this problem just replace in config.php

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO" by $config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

Answer (score 4):

It's right there in the CI user guide (Removing the index.php file): https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have .htaccess file create it and add this code in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Then in application/config/config.php find $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; and replace with $config['index_page'] = '';
P.S. the answer provided by Sarfraz works only in local machine. The one i provided works globally

Comment: That was complicated, compared to the suggestion in the official userguide.