# remove index.php of codeigniter subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

this is my directory:

```
-root
   -CI
     -application
     -system

   -sub-domain1 (codeigniter )
     -application

   -sub-domain2 (codeigniter )
     -application


   -www
     -folder1
     -folder2
     .....
     -folder10
     -sub-domain1
         -index.php (used for codeigniter)
     -sub-domain2
         -index.php (used for codeigniter)
     -file1.php
     -file2.php
     -file3.php
     .....
     -file10.php
     -index.php (used for codeigniter)
     - .htaccess
```

in my  application/config/config.php  is:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

I didn't have the sub-domain1 and sub-domain2 and I wanted to apply them now. I am using same system for all CIs. I used the following htaccess file and it works perfect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

now when I add sub-domain1 and sub-domain2 I have problem with index.php. for main CI index.php is gone but for sub-domains I don't know how i can do that.

```
www.mydomain.com/folder1/...           ok 

www.mydomain.com/controler/function    ok

www.sub-domain1.mydomain.com/index.php/controler/function  ok

www.sub-domain1.mydomain.com/controler/function  NOT ok
```

please help me. 
thanks

Comment: Mat be this could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455757/how-can-i-avoid-index-php-from-url-in-codelgniter/9455829#9455829

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to share the system directory across all of your CI installations, providing a central place for upgrades, and using less disk space.

Take a look in application/config/config.php

and the line: `$config['index_page'] = "index.php";`

should look like: `$config['index_page'] = "";`

Comment: Not sure if something got cut off there, but make sure this is the case for the application/config/config.php in each of the sub-domain's