# Why does CodeIgniter add /index.php/ to all URLs?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, routes

MY CodeIgnitor setup returns 404 on any URL expect the base url http://x.example.com/test/). When I try to visit an URL such as http://x.example.com/test/foobar/177 , I get the following 404:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index.php/foobar/177 was not found on this server.

When I check my web server log (this is Webfaction) it just says:

> [Mon Mar 19 12:23:45 2012] [error] [client 12.34.56.78] File does not
>   exist: /var/www/html/no_app_on_root.htmlindex.php

The way that a file path has been concatenated with index.php is odd, no?

Here's my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set which file that's fetched if only directory is specified
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# don't list category structures
Options -Indexes

# don't display .htaccess files
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#‘system’ can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn’t true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
#Submitted by Michael Radlmaier (mradlmaier)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don’t have mod_rewrite installed, all 404’s
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

My routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['foobar/177'] = "foobar/foobar_177";
$route['foobar/:num/add'] = "foobar/add";
$route['foobar/:num/review'] = "foobar/review";
$route['foobar/:num'] = "foobar";
```

my config.php (yes, the site is in a directory on a sub domain):

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://x.example.com/test/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455757/how-can-i-avoid-index-php-from-url-in-codelgniter/9455829#9455829.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule that is used to hide index.php from the url

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Sends all requests to /index.php/$1

And there aren't handlers for those, you need to specifically tell Apache that you don't want some URLs being redirected to `index.php`

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you.

Answer (score 0):

In the file: config.php

Edit this line:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

to:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

And your .htaccess file should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I have moved the system and application folders from the docroot, does that change anything?

Comment: I went ahead and tried you two changes. I still get 404 but at least the index.php isn't inserted in the urls:
The requested URL /test/foobar/177 was not found on this server.

Comment: This means that .htaccess file is not found in ROOT or code inside it doesn't run. make sure about it.

Comment: I've verified that .htaccess is processed by apache.